# How to direct download file from s3 path on clicking a button?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, yii2

Let's say I have the s3 url path of my file location. how can i directly download the file from that path to downloads folder on a click of a button?

Comment: Show what you've tried and the specific error / issue you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST('btnDownload')))
{
  $fileurl = 'your full path of s3 here';
  header("Content-type:application/pdf");
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
  readfile( $fileurl );
}
?>
```

Comment: yes! exactly what i need. thank you. but  this it work for all file types?

Comment: You have to specify file type in Content-type. For image, you can use Content-type:image/jpeg

Comment: What if this request is via AJAX?